# iPhone MapKit Framework to cache Google map for offline use

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit

I am planning on a map project for hiking on iPhone.

Since the area for hiking may not be covered by mobile network. Therefore, it is necessary to pre-cache the map (Google) of the area.

1) Can MapKit Framework support caching Google Map on iPhone locally ?
2) Can MapKit Framework support to use offline map during GPS-ing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Video from WWDC10 can be found here at hxxt://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ (sorry, can't post more then 1 link).

And here is a link for WWDC10 examples source (including TileMap):
http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645

You'll need an Apple account to download this 233 Mb ZIP :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately no, you cannot cache the google tiles (at least not in iOS 4.x). However, you can use an MKOverlay to create an overlay that displays and caches tiles from another map source like OpenStreetMap. Apple published an example TileMap overlay with their 2010 WWDC videos.

Comment: Just updating to say this comment is still true for iOS 5.0